# Crontab schedule every hour + custom rule

Tags: linux, cron, cron-task

I want to have cron run a task every `5th` minute from `20-24` hour, but also need it to run once at `00:15:00`. How do I accomplish this?

```
* */5 20,21,22,23,24 * * *
```

Comment: Just add a second line for the exception to the rule. Bear in mind `24` is not an hour of the day, it needs to be `00:15`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence is minute, hour, day of month, month, day of week, [user] command, so you have to put

```
*/5 0,20,21,22,23 * * * user /path/to/command
```

Comment: correct, but it will run +12 time, I need only once at 24:15, exists more optimal way ?

Comment: @Wizard 24:00 and, by extension, anything after it, is not a valid time... The sequence is 23:58, 23:59, 00:00, 00:01...

Comment: @twalberg btw it will run +12 times,  it's not optimal way